# Why does DART make my site SOOOOO slow?

Tags: wordpress, dart, dart-polymer

collegues!

I have been working in this website ( www.2winbet.gr ).

This week added a login interface from the website that was build as a small plugin in **Dart** using **polymer**.

It all *"works"*, and I am pretty happy with the speed I managed to build this component in Dart... BUT.... the site became HYPER slow after I added it!!...

If I remove it, the site is super fast again...

My dart code is so small and simple... I can really not understand where the issue is...

Could you please point me out what have I done wrong here? I can not believe this is the best Dart can do when added as a small component to a Wordpress site that has a few animations on it.

Thanks in forward

Comment: Are you manually compiling using dart2js, or using a Pub Build to generate your JavaScript?  A 'Pub Build' (from the Editor) will run the dart2js compiler with all of the possible compiler optimizations.  It will reduce the size of your JS input, and should help in overall page load/script execution time.

Comment: I'm doing right click over the main HTML file and clicking on "Run as Javascript" then I take the documents created in my "build" folder. I suppose there is a better way...?

Comment: Try clicking on the project in your workspace, then doing Tools -> Pub Build. See if that generates a smaller output.

Comment: Did it, and it does not really make any difference and the site keeps rendering very slow, specially when scrolling.

Comment: I am adding this 4 lines to the <head> tag:
<script src="http://www.2winbet.gr/login/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js"></script>
 <script src="http://www.2winbet.gr/login/packages/custom_element/custom-elements.debug.js"></script>
 <script src="http://www.2winbet.gr/login/packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
 <script src="http://www.2winbet.gr/login/login.html_bootstrap.dart.js"></script>

I have tested removing some of them and when I remove:
 <script src="http://www.2winbet.gr/login/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js"></script>

then all is FAST again BUT the login does't work!

Comment: You mention it's especially true when scrolling. This tells me it's not the dart script (compiled to javascript) specifically, but rather what you have it doing in the DOM (your animations need to be profiled). Check out http://jankfree.org/ for info about how to profile and optimze your site to find out where the issues are in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have asked John Messerly (who is working on Dart's Polymer):

This looks like it's Polymer's fault. Polymer depends on shadow DOM, but there seems to be no good way polyfill that functionality, without wrapping every node in the DOM.

The polyfill should be as fast as it possibly can get, but, due to the wrapping, there is some unavoidable cost. The actual overhead depends on the size of DOM and ratio of DOM operations to other app code. Possibly there are some particularly slow areas that haven't been hit yet, though. Especially event dispatch seems to be tricky to implement.

It would probably be interesting to get more data. (Feel free to reach out to us on the bug-tracker).

You would probably get the optimal performance on a native implementation. Chrome 35 is shipping it. Firefox is experimenting with an implementation.

You could also try to refactor your app so that the shadow DOM/Polymer.dart part is contained in an iFrame. This way it wouldn't affect other things on the page.

Comment: I realized while profiling that the shadow DOM was the black force pulling performance down. (We even joked at the office that there must be a reason MEAN why it's called "SHADOW"... uuuuhhh :) )

Indeed when running it natively everything is running smooth... But I cannot rely on it.

I will take the advice of refactoring the component into an iFrame. I believe this is the wisest option I have. I'll let know here how it went.

Thank you Florian

Comment: I have follow up question related to the iFram implementation. Maybe you can give me a hand on this one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404768/in-a-dart-website-component-that-is-in-an-iframe-how-can-i-query-elements-of-th