# In a DART website/component that is in an iFrame, how can I query elements of the parent window?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

collegues,

I'm solving my previous [**ISSUE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277533/why-does-dart-make-my-site-sooooo-slow/23297366?noredirect=1#23297366) where I had some performance issues involving the shadow DOM and heavy JS animations that were not done in DART.

The proposed solution for this was to move my DART component into an iFrame, to restrict the shadowDOM to the DOM of only that iFrame.

Now the QUESTION:

How can I query from my DART code elements from JS:window.parent? Any ideas on how can I register listeners to onCLick of elements on the parent iFrame? (I'm using Polymer as well)

Thanks in forward

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Sorry, deleted my Answer.

Comment: Your app is in the outer HTML document and you have an IFrame that loads it's own Dart script and a Polymer element and you want to access the outer HTML document from Polymer element code that is placed inside the IFrame?

Comment: In my opinion this doesn't work in both directions. From Document into the IFrame and also not from IFrame to outer Document.

Comment: I have a regular HTML document with some buttons on it, and an iFrame with a DART app inside that wants to listen to the onClick events of the buttons on the parent document.

I just to get the button in DART via myButton = querySelector('.myButton') but now that the button is on the parent HTML, I don't know how to get a reference to it from DART anymore.

Comment: If the requirements are so simple maybe my updated answer if of some help.

Comment: I cannot see your answer an longer :)

Answer (score 0):

Dart generally doesn't expose the DOM across iframe boundaries. You can communicate via postMessage though. I would suggest listening for "click" inside the iframe, then from within that handler, post a message to the window.parent.

The example in this post goes in the other direction (Dart hosting a JS child iframe), but it might be helpful:
http://japhr.blogspot.com/2013/05/a-necessary-evilgood-in-dart-iframe.html